# How to update PowerApps Dataflow owner with API?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, dataverse

I tried updating the value stored in Dataverse directly, like this:

```
PATCH <ORG-DOMAIN>/api/data/v9.2/msdyn_dataflows(<DATAFLOW-ID>)
Body = {"ownerid@odata.bind" = "/systemusers(<USER-ID>)"}
Headers = {"Authorization" = "Bearer <TOKEN>", "Content-Type" = "application/json"}
```

But I get:

```
"error":{"code":"0x80040265","message":"This operation is not supported."}
```

I also tried this:

```
POST <ORG-DOMAIN>/api/data/v9.2/msdyn_dataflows(<DATAFLOW-ID>)/owner_msdyn_dataflow/$ref
Body = {"@odata.id" = "<ORG-DOMAIN>/api/data/v9.2/systemusers(<USER-ID>)"} 
Headers = {"Authorization" = "Bearer <TOKEN>", "Content-Type" = "application/json"}
```

And got:

```
"error":{"code":"0x80060888","message":"The URI segment '$ref' is invalid after the segment 'owner_msdyn_dataflow'."}}
```